# Is there a benefit to using an enum in a FSM over just using a string?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, fsm

I want to create a finite state machine and most of the example code I can find uses enums and I was just wondering if it gives an advantage over just using a string or int to store the state.

With Enum:

class TrafficLight {
    enum State {
        RED, YELLOW, GREEN
    };

```
State state = State.GREEN;

public void iterate() throws InterruptedException {
    switch (this.state) {
    case RED:
        System.out.println("RED");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        this.state = State.GREEN;
        break;

    case GREEN:
        System.out.println("GREEN");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        this.state = State.YELLOW;
        break;

    case YELLOW:
        System.out.println("YELLOW");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        this.state = State.RED;
        break;
    }

}
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final TrafficLight a = new TrafficLight();
    while (true) {
        a.iterate();
    }
}
```

}

With String

public class TrafficLight {

```
String state = "GREEN";

public void iterate() throws InterruptedException {
    switch (state) {
        case "RED":
            System.out.println("RED");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            state = "GREEN";
            break;

        case "GREEN":
            System.out.println("GREEN");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            state = "YELLOW";
            break;

        case "YELLOW":
            System.out.println("YELLOW");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            state = "RED";
            break;
    }
}
```

}

(Both use the same main method)

They both seem to be exactly the same to me I am just wondering if there are any cases in which enums are better or a string wouldn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main advantage for `Enum` over `String` : this is more specifically typed as `Enum` specifies possible values.
This makes your code both more robust and also better documented.
For a FSM and more generally bounded values, it is what you are looking for.
But for problems/domains where possible values are defined at runtime and not at compile time (retrieving from a database or whatever), `Enum` is not the best candidate.

**Example of Enum interest in your case**

With Enum, it will not compile as `REDD` is not declared in the `State` enum class:

```
case REDD:
    System.out.println("RED");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    this.state = State.GREEN;
    break;
```

But with String, it will compile and just not work as expected :

```
case "REDD":
    System.out.println("RED");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    state = "GREEN";
    break;
```

**Enumerated values are instances of the enum class with own values for instance fields but also overriding abilities for instance methods**

This is another advantage of enum in the FSM or any domain where the enumerated values are associated to specific properties/processings and where according to enumerated value, the fields values or the method behavior could differ.

For example, here we specify the behavior to get the next transition :

```
enum State {
    YELLOW(){
        @Override
        public State next() {
            return RED;
        }
    },
    RED(){
        @Override
        public State next() {
            return GREEN;
        }
    },
    GREEN(){
        @Override
        public State next() {
            return YELLOW;
        }
    };
    public abstract State next();
}
```

Now, the enum holds enough logic to make the `switch` statement not needed any longer :

```
public void iterate() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(state);
    Thread.sleep(1000);         
    state = state.next();
}
```